# jQuery: How to reset Select2 without change event?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-select2

I am using Yii2 framework with a **select2** component that can let choose its color and show a sample:

[image: Select2 component to select a color]

```
$("#idColor").on("change", function() {
    showSample();
});
```

Also I have a button to reset the **Color** select2 component:

```
$("#idReset").click(function() {
    $("#idColor").val(null).trigger("change");
});
```

But when I click the Reset button the showSample() function is called. I only need to clear the selected value of **Color**.

Comment: Have a look at this, there is a solution https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3620

Comment: @nivas No need to refresh select2. Just use inbuilt method of changing selected value of select2 dropdown. See My answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$("#idReset").click(function() {
    $("#idColor").select2("val",null);
});
```

This will change the value of select2 dropdown without triggering change event.

Created jsFiddle for the same http://jsfiddle.net/fyhsz9ra/1733/.